# The input method toggled cursor monitoring on

Tags: flutter, dart, components

[image]

when i use this DefaultFormField Give me that Error => The input method toggled cursor monitoring on

ToDo App whit Flutter onTap methood Dosnen't work i chik it by print statment try create all this Form with class and same problem

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please [do not share code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13625293). You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77974885/edit) the post to include the code in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```dart
onTap: () => onTap,
```

You haven't invoked the function. Add parenthesis (`()`) to actually invoke the function:

```dart
onTap: () => onTap(),
```

Do the same fix to the `onSubmit` function as well.

---

Alternatively, you can change the type of the `onTap` parameter in `DefaultFormField`:

```dart
Widget DefaultFormField({
  // ...
  GestureTapCallback? onTap, // Change from Function? to GestureTapCallback?
```

and now you can use it as a [tear-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065771/what-is-a-tear-off-tearoff-tear-off):

```dart
onTap: onTap,
```

For `onFieldSubmitted`, the type is `ValueChanged<String>?`. You can see the parameter types by doing Ctrl+click on the `TextFormField` constructor or by looking at the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html).